# OpenDatasource or OpenRowSet are very slow after installing SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I am using `OpenDatasource` and `OpenRowSet` to import data from various sources.  We just installed SQL Server 2017 (actually had to uninstall 2016 and install 2017) and now they are running extremely slow. I have run `sp_updatestats` but haven't noticed much of a difference. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Turns out the slowness was due to changes IT had made that I was not made aware of.  They (IT) fixed it on their end and it now works fine.